# How to solve build errors using VS 2010 Ultimate on 32bit XP Sp3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp-sp3

Installed VS2010 Ultimate on my desktop workstation - Dell Precision T3500 (Windows 7 64bit OS), and on my IBM ThinkPad R51 (Windows XP Sp3 32bit).

I am having problems building solutions on the StinkPad, and cannot figure out why. As listed below, the build output for a compiler built ADO library lists the following errors:

c:\wpds\debug\msjro.tlh(196): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ConflictTables'
c:\wpds\debug\msjro.tlh(196): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\wpds\debug\msjro.tlh(196): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\wpds\debug\msjro.tlh(224): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetConflictTables'
c:\wpds\debug\msjro.tlh(224): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I have checked to make sure that all include, exe, and library paths are correct for all projects and solutions. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Bill

Comment: Can you how the code around the faulting line of code?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I believe I have run into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem when compiling for the first time with a new version of msado15.dll.  There are dependencies between msado15.dll and msjro.dll, as evidenced by these lines at the top of msjro.tlb:

```
// Cross-referenced type libraries:
//
//  #import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll"
//
```

In my case, the problem arose because I'm building my app on Windows 7, and the [SP1 update includes a breaking change in msado15.dll](http://jiangshengvc.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/breaking-change-in-ado-update-kb983246-included-in-windows-7-service-pack-1/) that will cause the application to fail on Windows XP.  When I fixed this problem using [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589) KB, my msado dll problems were fixed but my msjro.tlb stopped compiling.
There is probably a way to update msjro to reference the desired/correct msado (in my case, msado60_Backcompat.tlb as installed in the KB), but if you're using [CADODatabase classes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/caaadoclass1.aspx?msg=1667398) defined in ado2.cpp and ado2.h, and if you're not using jet-specific features, a simpler fix is to just comment-out the portions of ado2.h and ado2.cpp that reference jet.
I just commented out this line in ado2.h:

```
//#import <MSJRO.DLL> no_namespace rename("ReplicaTypeEnum", "_ReplicaTypeEnum")
```

and also #ifdef'd out all of the implementations of CJetEngine methods in ado2.cpp, and that worked for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  Then I compared the MSJRO.TLH created on WinXP to the one created on Win7.  On WinXP the declaration was

```
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr ...
```

on Win7 it was

```
_RecordsetPtr ...
```

I guessed that the problem might be related to namespaces.  MSADO15.TLH defines a namespace -"ADODB".  So I placed:

```
using namespace ADODB;
```

before my import of the Jet.

```
#import "MSJRO.DLL"
```

This got rid of the errors for me.